# Converting jQuery Datatables to server-side php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatables

From the outset - I am not an incredibly proficient php developer, so this is likely an easy problem to solve for some of you. That said, I am learning and do appreciate any insight as to "why" something does/doesn't work. I have previously reached out in the Datatables forums and tried many things on my own with no luck.

Here's the issue:

I've been doing this client-side successfully and been getting all the formatting correct. I am struggling to convert into server side using the script here - http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql

The data is coming in just fine, it is the formatting of different columns I am struggling with. Here is one example - I have a certain column that looks like this using client-side:

```
<td>
  <div class="text-center">                                                                     
       <?php                                                                                     
           if( is_null($row["FIELD1"]))                                                       
               {echo "<div class=\"label label-inverse\">Not Started</div><div class=\"progress progress-warning slim\"><div class=\"bar\" style=\"width: 15%\"></div></div>";}                                  
           elseif( is_null($row["Final"]) && ($row["Status"]==='1') && is_null($row["Create"]))   
               {echo "<div class=\"label label-info\">In Progress</div><div class=\"progress progress-info slim\"><div class=\"bar\" style=\"width: 30%\"></div></div>";}                                        
           elseif( is_null($row["Final"]) && ($row["Status"]==='0') && ($row["MAP"]==='1') && is_null($row["Create"]))                                                                                       
               {echo "<div class=\"label label-info\">In Progress</div><div class=\"progress progress-info slim\"><div class=\"bar\" style=\"width: 20%\"></div></div>";}                                        
           elseif( is_null($row["Final"]) && ($row["Status"]==='0') && ($row["VAP"]==='1') && is_null($row["Create"]))                                                                                       
               {echo "<div class=\"label label-info\">In Progress</div><div class=\"progress progress-info slim\"><div class=\"bar\" style=\"width: 25%\"></div></div>";}
           elseif( is_null($row["Final"]) && ($row["Status"]==='0') && ($row["LAP"]==='1') && is_null($row["Create"]))                                                                                       
               {echo "<div class=\"label label-info\">In Progress</div><div class=\"progress progress-info slim\"><div class=\"bar\" style=\"width: 30%\"></div></div>";} 
           elseif( is_null($row["Final"]) && isset($row["Create"]) && is_null($row["Synch"]))          
               {echo "<div class=\"label label-info\">In Progress</div><div class=\"progress progress-info slim\"><div class=\"bar\" style=\"width: 45%\"></div></div>";}                                        
           elseif( is_null($row["Final"]) && isset($row["Synch"])  && is_null($row["Config"]))           
               {echo "<div class=\"label label-info\">In Progress</div><div class=\"progress progress-info slim\"><div class=\"bar\" style=\"width: 60%\"></div></div>";}                                        
           elseif( is_null($row["Final"]) && isset($row["Config"])  && is_null($row["AllSet"]))   
               {echo "<div class=\"label label-info\">In Progress</div><div class=\"progress progress-info slim\"><div class=\"bar\" style=\"width: 75%\"></div></div>";}                                        
           elseif( is_null($row["Final"]) && isset($row["AllSet"]))                      
               {echo "<div class=\"label label-info\">In Progress</div><div class=\"progress progress-info slim\"><div class=\"bar\" style=\"width: 90%\"></div></div>";}                                        
           else                                                                                  
               {echo "<div class=\"label label-success\">Completed</div><div>in ";} {echo($row["diff"]);} {echo "</div>";}
       ?>    
   </div>
</td>
```

I just can't figure out how to get that "Translated" to the format outlined here:

```
if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
            {
                /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
            }
```

Simpler ones like this (formatting the date and changing the display of 0 or 1 to yes/no) I have been able to figure out:

```
<td><div class="text-center"><?php echo date("m/d/Y H:i A", strtotime($row["SDate"]));?></div></td>
<td>
    <div class="text-center">
        <?php if( is_null($row["Status"])){echo "<div class=\"label label-warning\">Checking...</div>";}else{echo ($row["Status"] ? 'yes': 'no');}?>
     </div>
</td>
```

as it "Translates" to:

```
if ( $aColumns[$i] == "SDate" )                                                              
            {  
                $row[] = date("m/d/Y H:i A", strtotime(($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ])));                            
            } 
else if ( $aColumns[$i] == "Status" )                                                              
           {  
                $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]) ? 'yes' : 'no';                                             
            }
```

But I'm having trouble getting things like all those extra conditionals working. Any guidance is appreciated.

UPDATE:

apparently my example is too complicated & misses the point. Here is what may be an easier example:

Depending on the status of the column "Exempt", I want to display "Checking" if it is null, and either yes or no if it is 1 or 0. Currently, the functioning client-side code looks like this:

```
 <td>
     <div>
         <?php 
              if( is_null($row["Exempt"]))
                  {echo "<div class=\"label label-warning\">Checking...</div>";}
              else 
                  {echo ($row["Exempt"] ? 'yes': 'no');}
         ?> 
     </div>
 </td>
```

BUT, I can't get it to format correctly when using the style/formatting shown in this script http://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_mysql (also shown above). So, how do I fill in the following for that?

```
 if ( $aColumns[$i] == "Exempt" )
 {
      $row[]= //?????I can't get this part to work correctly
 }
```

Comment: Your problem is that that 10-else monstrosity isn't a column, it's a calculated output of at least 11 different columns. That is very bad database design. You need to separate the concerns of each column and figure out what each of them does by itself. I mean, it's clear that if the status is "In Progress", then Final IS NULL and Created is not. What is Created if the "something" was started? Who knows. You need to define your columns.

Comment: Correct, that 10-else monstrosity is not a column in a database - It is a column in a table that displays the status of what is happening in the other columns, so it is constantly changing. The database is tracking the change in a user's account, moving from one system to another.

Comment: That is to say, the 10-else column above is for display purposes only. The database itself is very clearly laid out.  To ask this question another way: How do I do an if/else within the constraints of the outlined format referenced above to echo something different based on the status of a column in the database? I hope that clarifies.